# Make webpack ignore a directory

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webpack, webpack-2, webpack-file-loader, webpack-plugin

I'm making a chrome extension that injects content scripts. I don't want Content scripts to be processed by webpack.

My directory structure:

```
/extension
|-manifest.json
|--scripts
   |- background.js
   |- content
      |-- script1.js
      |-- script2.js
      |-- ...
```

Here's my gulp task that calls webpack:

```
gulp.task('js', (cb) => {

  return gulp.src(['source/scripts/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function(errors) {

      }
    }))
    .pipe(named())
    .pipe(gulpWebpack({
      watch: args.watch,
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            enforce: "pre",
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: "json-loader"
          },
          {
            enforce: "pre",
            test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/,
            loader: "file-loader?name=img/[name].[ext]",
          },
          {
            enforce: "pre",
            test: /content\//,
            loader: "file-loader?name=content/[name].[ext]",
          },
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            exclude: [
              /content/
            ]
          }
        ],
      },
    }, null, (err, stats) => {
      log(`Finished '${colors.cyan('js')}'`, stats.toString({
        chunks: false,
        colors: true,
        cached: false,
        children: false
      }));
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`/scripts`))
});
```

I want to keep the directory structure in the build directory and not get the files inside `content/` to be parsed, ie. to use the `file-loader`

But they're just getting parsed and my `pre` rule for content scripts is getting ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a separate gulp task to copy those sort of scripts without any processing and excluded that same directory from the gulp task that calls webpack

Answer (score 0):

Webpack will only process the files which are required by the script which you are compiling. It is not possible to do so as excluding directories with dependencies would break your project.

Comment: Gulp is providing all js files